# How to calculate QTextEdit height accurately by its contents to get rid of vertical scrollbars?

Tags: qt

I need a QTextEdit widget which height grows or shrinks to the size of the inner content. I didn't find built-in solution and decided to make my own with connections to `&QTextEdit::textChanged` signals that will update size of the widget at runtime. In the code snippet I flattened my custom component to raw `QTextEdit` for simplicity. The problem is that calculation via `QFontMetrics` is inaccurate, a vertical scrollbar appears with only some pixels to scroll

[image]

I want to get rid of any vertical scrollbars in these text widgets.

However, I don't need to get rid of horizontal scrollbars and here is the second problem arises. Seemingly, horizontal scrolls occupy space in the viewport of the text widget and its internal height shrinks by the height of the scrollbar itself

[image]

```
void TestWindow::setupUi(QWidget *parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *v_box0 = new QVBoxLayout(parent);
    v_box0->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    QVBoxLayout *v_scroll_layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    v_scroll_layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    v_scroll_layout->setSpacing(0);
    v_scroll_layout->setAlignment(::Qt::AlignTop);

    QWidget *scroll_content = new QWidget();
    scroll_content->setLayout(v_scroll_layout);

    QScrollArea *v_scroll = new QScrollArea();
    v_scroll->setWidgetResizable(true);
    v_scroll->setWidget(scroll_content);
    v_box0->addWidget(v_scroll);

    QSize size;

    QTextEdit *edit0 = new QTextEdit();
    edit0->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
    edit0->setText("Hello World 1\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11");
    edit0->setFont(viewer_font);
    size = edit0->fontMetrics().size(0, edit0->document()->toPlainText());
    edit0->document()->setDocumentMargin(0);
    edit0->setMinimumHeight(size.height());

    QTextEdit *edit1 = new QTextEdit();
    edit1->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
    edit1->setText("New item");
    edit1->setFont(viewer_font);
    size = edit1->fontMetrics().size(0, edit1->document()->toPlainText());
    edit1->document()->setDocumentMargin(0);
    edit1->setMinimumHeight(size.height());

    v_scroll_layout->addWidget(edit0);
    v_scroll_layout->addWidget(edit1);

    setFixedHeight(300);
}
```

Comment: I think [`QTextEdit::document`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#document-prop) combined with [`QTextDocument::size`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextdocument.html#size-prop) will give you what you need.

Comment: @G.M. it seems you're right but it doesn't take horizontal scrollbar into account

Comment: So just check whether or not the horizontal scrollbar is visible.  If it is then add its height to the height of the document, right?